# Given an index position, how can I split out the sentence that that position lies in?

Tags: javascript, nlp, string-parsing

I'm using JavaScript, and my text is:

```
Dana's places, we're having people coming to us people wanna buy condos. They want to move quickly and we're just losing out on a lot of great places. Really what would you say this?
```

If I have an index position of `6`, I want to get just the first sentence: `Dana's places, we're having people coming to us people wanna buy condos.`

If I have an index position of `80`, I want to get just the second sentence: `They want to move quickly and we're just losing out on a lot of great places.`

How can I parse the sentence based on position?

Comment: How does an index correlate to the return value? Are you saying that if the index is within that sentence, you want to return just that sentence?

Comment: The index is just the place in the string that is specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to just

Split on periods. 
Get the length of the strings.
Determine where the index lands based sentence length.

Considering you need to split on "?, !" as well, you just need to loop through the sentences and flatten them further. Aka, split again.

Honestly, probably cleaner to use a regex and group.

**Here is the regex version**

```
    const paragraph = "Dana's places, we're having people coming to us people wanna buy condos. They want to move quickly and we're just losing out on a lot of great places. Really what would you say this?"


    /**
     * Finds sentence by character index
     * @param index 
     * @param paragraph 
     */
    function findSentenceByCharacterIndex(index, paragraph) {

        const regex = /([^.!?]*[.!?])/gm

        const matches = paragraph.match(regex);

        let cursor = 0;

        let sentenceFound;

        for (const sentence of matches) {

            sentenceFound = sentence;

            cursor += sentence.length;

            if( cursor > index )
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return sentenceFound;
    }


    const found = findSentenceByCharacterIndex(5, paragraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split on the periods. The string object has a prototype method called split that returns an array of the split string. In the example below `str` is a variable that holds your string.

```
const str = 'first sentence. Second sentence. third sentence';
const sentences = str.split('.');
sentences[0] // first sentence
sentences[1] // second sentence, etc
```

Comment: But I don't necessarily want the first or the second sentence. I want the sentence that the index of the specified character is in. I also want to split on ? and !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use `Array.split`, it may be best to do some traditional character by character parsing of the string. Since we know what index we're looking for, we can simply look around for the beginning and end of a sentence.

How does a sentence end? Typically with either a **`.`, `!`, or a `?`** - knowing this we can test for these characters and decide what part of the string we should slice off and return back to the program. If before our chosen index there is no `sentence enders`(a.e. **?!.**) we assume that the beginning of the string is the beginning of the current sentence(0) - we do the same with after our chosen index, except we assign `str.length` if there is no sentence ender after the index.

```js
let str = "Dana's places, we're having people coming to us people wanna buy condos. They want to move quickly and we're just losing out on a lot of great places. Really what would you say this?";

let getSentence = (ind, str) => {
  let beg, end, flag, sentenceEnder = ["!", ".", "?"];
  Array.from(str).forEach((c, c_index) => {
  if(c_index < ind && sentenceEnder.includes(c)) {
   beg = c_index + 1;
  }
    if (flag) return;
    if (c_index >= ind && sentenceEnder.includes(c)) {
      end = c_index;
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  end = end || str.length;
  beg = beg || 0;
  return str.slice(beg, end);
}

console.log(getSentence(10, str));
console.log(getSentence(80, str));
```